# Issues overriding page field value in pageview tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, universal-analytics

I decided to override page value which is send to GA on page view. Reasons for override were:

- Not always page title is unique (some pages have one title)
- Page URLs are ugly and meaning less and looking at URL it will be hard to understand which page it is.

So I explicitly provide page value.

Like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': '/store/books/viewlist'})
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a good practice to override page value?
2. Why in Google Analytics *Behavior -> Events -> Pages* in page column I see page URL (thus "/store/driver?page=777&action=viewlist") not the page value what is sent? Is this a GA bug? In other places, for instance, in *Behavior -> Site content -> All pages* in page column I see correct page value (thus "/store/books/viewlist").